# Installing https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem on rails 6 alpha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, webpacker

How do you install the bootstrap gem (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem) on rails 6?

The bootstrap README asks us to add things to application.js
but rails 6 doesn't seem to have an application.js in the usual place.

[ Rails 6.0.0.alpha ]
`bundle exec rails new noname --edge --database=postgresql --webpacker=react`

Answer (score 7):

If you use webpacker, you may want to use the npm package of bootstrap

```
yarn add bootstrap@4.0.0 popper.js
```

and

```
# app/javascript/packs/application.js
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
```

and inside stylesheets.scss

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Please look at the complete steps here: https://medium.com/@coorasse/goodbye-sprockets-welcome-webpacker-3-0-ff877fb8fa79

Answer (score 2):

This is the most basic solution for me:

Install `bootstrap`, `jquery` and `popper.js` with yarn:

```
$ yarn add bootstrap
$ yarn add jquery
$ yarn add popper.js
```

Then require `bootstrap` JS and CSS in `app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

```
require('bootstrap')
require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')
```

**Note:** If you need to use SCSS to customize Bootstrap then this solution is not proper for you. Use @coorasse's solution above.