# How do I install bootstrap 4 on a rails 6 (Rails 6.0.0.beta3 at github/rails HEAD) application?

Tags: bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-6

What I tried (script below) - I say it's not working because
when I paste the [jumbotron example from bootstrap](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/site/content/docs/4.3/examples/jumbotron/index.html) in to my application html file I don't see the bootstrap css "effects".

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex

rm -rf /tmp/template || true
mkdir /tmp/template
cd /tmp/template

echo "source 'https://rubygems.org'" > Gemfile
echo "gem 'rails', git: 'https://github.com/rails/rails.git'" >> Gemfile
bundle

bundle exec rails new . --force --dev --database=postgresql

perl -pi.bak -e 's/gem .rails.*/gem "rails", github: "rails\/rails"/' Gemfile


bundle install

# Devise
echo "gem 'devise'" >> Gemfile
bundle
bundle exec rails generate devise:install
bundle exec rails generate devise User
bundle exec rails generate devise:views
bundle exec rake db:drop || true
bundle exec rails db:create || true
bundle exec rails db:migrate || true

## Bootstrap - Commented out not working
```

[ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54253872)

[ref1](https://medium.com/@coorasse/goodbye-sprockets-welcome-webpacker-3-0-ff877fb8fa79)

Comment: If you are using webpack, you can refer this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54253872/6138595  And refer to this article to using Webpack to achive this: https://medium.com/@guilhermepejon/how-to-install-bootstrap-4-3-in-a-rails-6-app-using-webpack-9eae7a6e2832

Comment: your medium article is interesting ill try it

Comment: Yes sure. Let us know if it works

Comment: why do some folks use prepend ( https://www.google.com/search?q=bootstrap+webpacker++"plugins.prepend"+NOT+append )

Comment: your medium article worked for me on beta3

Comment: Glad to know it worked. Cheers :)